# How to disable the default option in dropdown list

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to disable the default option given in dropdown list.
e.g. There are three values in dropdown list

```
["Select a status", "Processing", "Completed"]
```

I want to apply disabled and selected properties on "Select a status".

Can you please tell me how to do this? I am not able to use both the properties on same value.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `options_for_select`

```
<%= select_tag(:city_id, options_for_select(["Free", "Basic", "Advanced", "Super Platinum"], :disabled => "Super Platinum", :selected => "Super Platinum")) %>
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but it doesn't make "Super Platinum" a default option.

Answer (score 1):

Following works for me

```
<%= select("post", "person_id", options_for_select(["Free", "Basic", "Advanced", "Super Platinum"], :disabled => "Super Platinum", :selected => "Super Platinum" ))  %>
```